How big of a notch/hole in a stud can a stud shoe support?
A load bearing 2x4 stud can only be notched 25% of its width. If it's more, my understanding is that a stud shoe can be used to reinforce it. But what's the limit for a stud shoe? If it's 80% notched, can you still use one? What about if it's 95% notched, or entirely cut through? Where is the limit?
It also doesn't necessarily have to be a notch; the same question would apply for a hole as well.

up to 2 -3/8 inch

Also depends if just one stud or a bunch of studs.  One stud, the others will help hold the load.

Depends on the product. Read its literature.

@isherwood, haven't seen a single one that actually says. I was mostly looking at simpson, but they don't specify.
